# Slice np.array, rankdata and return ranks to parent of slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I started with the following array, that is a set of 3 values for 3 fields that I need to rank for the 3 objects with ids 123,124,126.  Ultimately in a report I will look up the values and ranks by the object_id.

```
ha = np.array(
      [
        (123,5,3,4),
        (124,4,999,3),
        (126,6,5,999)
      ], dtype=[
        ('object_id','int8'),('val1','int16'),
       ('val2','int16'),('val3','int16')])
```

I am not sure exactly how best to rank them and store that data.  My plan was to make a copy of this array, use scipy.stats.rankdata to rank field and store values.

```
ra = np.copy(ha)
ra['val1'] = rankdata(ha['val1'], method='min').astype(int)
```

This works except for the case when the object doesn't have a value for a specific field it default to 999 and then these objects need to be removed from the ranking. This is what my code looks like now:

```
ra = np.copy(ha)
subset = ha[np.where(ha['val1'] < 999)
ranks = rankdata(subset['val1'], method='min').astype(int)
```

My problem now is how to get the ranks values back into my ra array in the correct position? It is a subset of ha, which means it is no longer the same size as ha or ra

EDIT:
This is the result I need to end up with after taking subsets of the first array and rankings the values < 999 from lowest to highest.

```
ra = np.array(
          [
            (123,2,1,2),
            (124,1,0,1),
            (126,3,2,0)
          ], dtype=[
            ('object_id','int8'),('val1','int16'),
           ('val2','int16'),('val3','int16')])
```

**SOLUTION**

```
>>> ha = np.array(
       [
         (123,5,3,4),
         (124,4,999,3),
         (126,6,5,999)
       ], dtype=[
         ('object_id','int8'),('val1','int16'),
        ('val2','int16'),('val3','int16')])
>>> c = np.copy(ha)
>>> i = ha['val2']<999
>>> c['val2'] = 0
>>> c['val2'][i] = rankdata(ha['val2'][i], method='max').astype(int)
>>> c['val2']
     array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int16)
```

Comment: I would describe it as a subset, rather than slice.  In Python/numpy `slice` has a specific meaning (e.g. `slice(start,stop,step` or `[start:step:stop]`

Comment: Aside: if you're working with named columns, you should consider using a pandas DataFrame instead of a raw numpy ndarray.  In this particular case it's not that much of an advantage, but it will be in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you want (using a simpler sort on a 1d array)?

```
In [14]: x=np.array([1,0,999,3,2])

In [15]: i=x<999

In [16]: np.sort(x[i])
Out[16]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [17]: y=x.copy()

In [18]: y[i]=np.sort(x[i])

In [19]: y
Out[19]: array([  0,   1, 999,   2,   3])
```

Comment: Not exactly because I need the new array to have the actual rank position value and not just the values ordered.  For example:  [3,5,2] => [2,3,1]

Comment: But am I putting the values in the right place?  I'm not focusing on the values themselves.

Comment: Ok after working through it your method definitely works. I will post solution above.